# Dynamically add button at certain position

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to dynamically add buttons in a loop after some specific text. I have a site for questions and answer and I want to have a 'vote as best answer' button for each question. Consider the following:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < num_of_answers ; i++)
{
     //print the answer...DONE
     //add button to mark it as best... How?
}
```

It can obviously lead to a certain script, my point is, when that button is added, it always goes to the bottom of the page and not near the question where I want it. I know how to add a button, but how do I position it where I want it?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your view with any relevant CSS?

Comment: OK so it almost works. Post the code which actually creates the buttons (and the RELEVANT html/aspx markup, not the whole site!).

Answer (score 0):

it is not good idea to make controls dynamically in ASP.NET because of it is hard or in some complex cases impossible to handle their events .

instead you can use simply Repeater control.

here is the Examples

[MSDN - repeater document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[C-sharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/)

I can make an example for you if you want.